# Saving Outlook Attachement with password then forward

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to build a rule script that saves an outlook attachment (excel specific) to a the user's hard drive. I then need to add a password to this excel attachment and then forward it.

Saving and forwarding emails/attachments is simple enough using the VBA Outlook developer tools (see below). However, I am running into issues with adding a password to this attachment. Is this possible or do I need an outside script/program to do this task? Furthermore, do you have any other suggestions?

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
    saveFolder = "c:\"
     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
     Call SendEmail
End Sub

Public Sub SendEmail()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim blRunning As Boolean

     'get application
    blRunning = True
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If olApp Is Nothing Then
        Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
        blRunning = False
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With olMail
        .Subject = "My email with attachment"
        .Recipients.Add "jlanz@mmyemail.com"
        .Attachments.Add "C:\test123.xlsx"
        .Body = "Here is an email"
        .Send 
    End With
If Not blRunning Then olApp.Quit

Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect you're going to need an outside program for this.

Comment: add a reference to the Excel library then open the file, add the password, save it and then attach it and send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment you need to add a reference to the excel library.  Then you can set a password using the example below.

```
Sub ProtectExcelWorkbook(filePath As String)
Dim pw As String
pw = "password"

    Dim eApp As Excel.Application
    Dim eBook As Excel.Workbook
    Set eApp = New Excel.Application
    Set eBook = eApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath)    
    eBook.Password = pw
    eBook.Save

    Set eBook = Nothing
    eApp.Quit
    Set eApp = Nothing

End Sub


Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
    saveFolder = "c:\"
     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
          ProtectExcelWorkbook saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
     Call SendEmail
End Sub
```